# How can I use CSS Modules from my main global scss stylesheet?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to extend the CSS Loader for Nuxt.js so I can use modules within my global .scss files in `assets/scss/screen.scss`.

This is taken from the [Vue.js site](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage).

```js
// webpack.config.js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              // enable CSS Modules
              modules: true,
              // customize generated class names
              localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:8]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Problem is I don't know where to put this in my Nuxt.config.js for what I have tried fails.

If I place here:

```js
build: {
    extend(...){
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
            'vue-style-loader',
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                // enable CSS Modules
                modules: true,
                // customize generated class names
                localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:8]'
                }
            }
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

It throws

`Error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined at  at node_modules\@nuxtjs\style-resources\lib\module.js:88:18`

I am confused because I am already extending it successfully in my nuxt.config.js to allow for CSS modules INSIDE of each component.

```js
loaders: {
    cssModules: {
        modules: {
        localIdentName: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
            ? "[hash:base64:6]"
            : "[local]--[hash:base64:6]"
        }
    }
},
```

But I can't call a CSS class as a module from my main 'global' stylesheet. No error, it just can't find it.

/assets/scss/screen.scss

```js
.triangle{
    background:red;
}
```

Can't be linked-to in my Nuxt file as

```html
<div :class="$style.triangle"></div>
```

Just like it can if I add the CSS directly within my module. I wonder why I can't access CSS Modules this way? But I can if it's directly within a component using

```html
<style module lang="scss"></style>
```

Am I able to use CSS modules from a main global stylesheet?

Comment: Have you read this [article](https://redonion.se/en/css-modules-in-nuxt-js/) yet?

Comment: His tests in Nuxt for external modules don’t work either it would seem: “ This does however not seem to work in the same way for Nuxt.js projects, at least not judging from the tests I did with a project setup as described below.” :(